# Hidden/exposed station in MACA protocol

Tags: computer-science, network-protocols, wireless

I'm trying to understand how the MACA protocol solves the hidden/exposed station problem in wireless comunication networks.
As far as I understand, the hidden station problem can't occur but I'm not sure about the exposed station problem.
Is there a scenario where a station who wants to send will not send because it sensed a CTS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maman 14?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_Access_with_Collision_Avoidance_for_Wireless#Unsolved_problems